# Is this a bug in busterjs unit testing framework?

Tags: bash, node.js, unit-testing, buster.js

I'm running my tests in busterjs and there's an error in one of them - but I'm still getting a 0 return code. This is causing my CI server to show the build status as "green" when it should be "red"

```
iMac:tests caseyflynn$ buster test
API GET /users: ..
Module components/apiAuth: .........
Module components/controllers: ....
Module components/routeParrot: ..F.

Deferred: API GET /users GET /api/users "client_super_admin" returns all users for given client
Deferred: API GET /users GET /api/users "super_admin" returns all users
Deferred: API GET /users GET /api/users "client_admin" returns all users for given client
Deferred: API GET /users GET /api/users "client_delegate" returns all users for given client
Deferred: API GET /users GET /api/users "client_auditor" returns all users for given client

Failure: Module components/routeParrot Modifies socket.io request to API
    [assert.calledWith] Expected function spy() {} to be called with arguments { headers: [], method: "get", url: "/api/users" }, { jsonAPIRespond: function () {} }
    spy({
  data: { headers: [], method: "get", url: "/users" },
  headers: [],
  method: "get",
  requestType: "socketio",
  url: "/api/users"
}, { jsonAPIRespond: function () {} })
    at Object.buster.testCase.Modifies socket.io request to API (./componentsTests/routeParrotTest.js:70:21)

4 test cases, 19 tests, 44 assertions, 1 failure, 0 errors, 0 timeouts, 5 deferred
Finished in 0.044s
iMac:tests caseyflynn$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: *Should* `buster` have a non-zero exit code? `buster` itself exited successfully; it ran the tests you provided and reported the failures it found.

Comment: @chepner, yes usually the expected behavior of a testing framework is to exit non-zero if any test conditions fail

https://github.com/busterjs/buster/issues/219

"Expected behaviour would be that a missing configuration as well as failing tests return a non-zero exit code."

Comment: I'm using buster with grunt-buster and it let the CI fail if a test fail. And all the task does is just to check the exit code (https://github.com/busterjs/grunt-buster/blob/master/tasks/buster.js#L122). So are you sure about the zero exit code?